# Meaning of "advance" and "develop"

Tags: meaning

The context:

> P1: We lost nearly a decade of research because of the moratorium on embryonic stem cell research.
>
> P2: The moratorium [on embryonic stem cell research] aided in the advancement science made elsewhere on stem cell research so don't get your panties twisted.

Definition of *advance* from OALD:

> If knowledge, technology, etc. advances, it develops and improves.

I understand the term *develop* has many senses and I am unsure of which is the proper definition of develop for this context from the dictionaries.

Comment: Google Books gives just **2** results for ["get your panties twisted"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get+your+panties+twisted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as against **843** ["get your panties in a twist"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get+your+panties+in+a+twist%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I suggest speaker P2 doesn't have a good grasp of standard English, and this question is therefore Too Localised.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what advance and develop means. Sorry my English is poor.

Comment: ELU isn't really here to provide definitions of common words. But I'm surprised you should have difficulties with *advance/develop/improve* (which all mean the same in your specific context).

Comment: so develop means improve here precisely?

Comment: In this exact context, yes. But in another context, [an aggressive cancer could **develop** quickly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cancer+developed+quickly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example. That would be *getting worse* from the patient's point of view, not *improving*.

Comment: Delete or close General Reference.